# How to have a row of pictures centered and under each other with a border around each picture?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I could have each picture centered in the middle of the page and under each other in a row of 4. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

My coding can be seen below:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
body {
 color: #333;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
}
h1,
h1+p {
 margin: 30px 15px 0;
 font-weight: 300;
}
h1+p a {
 color: #333;
}
h1+p a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
 margin: 60px 15px 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-weight: 300;
}
h2 span {
 margin-left: 1em;
 color: #aaa;
 font-size: 85%;
}
.column {
 margin: 15px 15px 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.column:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.column::after {
 content: '';
 clear: both;
 display: block;
}
.column div {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 0 0 25px;
 padding: 0;
}
.column div:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.column div span {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -20px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 display: block;
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #444;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
}
figure {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
}
figure:hover+span {
 bottom: -36px;
 opacity: 1;
}


/* Opacity #1 */
.hover11 figure img {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover11 figure:hover img {
 opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</br>
<span class="textformat1"><center><b>Gallery</b></span></center>


<center>
 <div class="hover11 column">
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img1fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/10647762_1068348719862622_2085603419_n.png" alt="10647762_1068348719862622_2085603419_n" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   <span>Hover</span>
  </div>
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img2fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/12325991_1059629627401198_1870410396_o.jpg" alt="12325991_1059629627401198_1870410396_o" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img3fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/12381186_1068348869862607_2103570970_o.jpg" alt="12381186_1068348869862607_2103570970_o" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img4fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/1932078_1068348593195968_1861115484_n.jpg" alt="1932078_1068348593195968_1861115484_n" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img5fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/img5thumbnail.jpg" alt="img5thumbnail" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img6fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/12404434_1068348596529301_270753597_n.jpg" alt="12404434_1068348596529301_270753597_n" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img7fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/12404946_1068348673195960_1063608705_o.jpg" alt="12404946_1068348673195960_1063608705_o" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img8fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/12405008_1068348669862627_440250682_o.jpg" alt="12405008_1068348669862627_440250682_o" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img9fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/12413879_10683487763195950_1758712787_o.jpg" alt="12413879_10683487763195950_1758712787_o" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img10fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/12358479235.jpg" alt="12358479235" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <figure><a class="fancybox" href="images/img11fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/124522465_1068348823195945_750893117_o.jpg" alt="124522465_1068348823195945_750893117_o" width="300" height="200"></a></figure>
   
  </div>
 </div>
</center>



<br/>
```

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the `<center></center>` tags because those are actually getting removed/depreciated from HTML soon. There is now a modern CSS-only way that you're supposed to use, to center stuff. Same for `<b>` tags! Nowadays, any formatting, should be done using CSS, and not using the "old style" stuff like `font=""` or `<center>` or `<b>` or `width=""` or `height=""`. You shouldn't use `figure` either. Basically .. I'm guessing that you learned HTML from a really old book or really old tutorial? This was how HTML worked in around 2001 but now, that's just not how its coded anymore, and the only reason it still kinda "works" is because browsers try and do a "compatibility" thing when they see old-style-html. It will stop working at all, in the future, because of depreciation. Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve with figure? I'll rewrite the CSS for you, without using the figure thingy. But anyways ... in your case, to center the images (and fix other problems) I've rewritten your code to look like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<br>
<div class="textformat1 text_center">Gallery</div>

<div class="hover11 column">
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img1fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/10647762_1068348719862622_2085603419_n.png" alt="10647762_1068348719862622_2085603419_n" ></a>
        <span>Hover</span>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img2fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/12325991_1059629627401198_1870410396_o.jpg" alt="12325991_1059629627401198_1870410396_o">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img3fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/12381186_1068348869862607_2103570970_o.jpg" alt="12381186_1068348869862607_2103570970_o">
    </a>    
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img4fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/1932078_1068348593195968_1861115484_n.jpg" alt="1932078_1068348593195968_1861115484_n">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img5fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/img5thumbnail.jpg" alt="img5thumbnail">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img6fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/12404434_1068348596529301_270753597_n.jpg" alt="12404434_1068348596529301_270753597_n">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img7fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/12404946_1068348673195960_1063608705_o.jpg" alt="12404946_1068348673195960_1063608705_o">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img8fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/12405008_1068348669862627_440250682_o.jpg" alt="12405008_1068348669862627_440250682_o">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img9fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/12413879_10683487763195950_1758712787_o.jpg" alt="12413879_10683487763195950_1758712787_o">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img10fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/12358479235.jpg" alt="12358479235">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="fancybox" href="images/img11fullsize.jpg">
    <img class="image_center figure" src="images/124522465_1068348823195945_750893117_o.jpg" alt="124522465_1068348823195945_750893117_o">
    </a>
</div>


</div><!--//end container-->
<br>
```

**CSS**

```
.image_center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.text_center {
    text-align: center;    }

.figure {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;  }

.figure:hover+span {
    bottom: -36px;
    opacity: 1;   }


/* Opacity #1 */
.hover11 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover11 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .5;



body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1,
h1+p {
    margin: 30px 15px 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1+p a {
    color: #333;
}
h1+p a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
    margin: 60px 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h2 span {
    margin-left: 1em;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 85%;
}
.column {
    margin: 15px 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.column:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.column::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.column div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
}
.column div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.column div span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I applied this code, but it removes a hover effect I had applied onto the pictures. and doesn't seem to center them on my end, as in each picture side by side.

Comment: That's why I asked you to tell me the details about the "figure" and asked you what you wanted the hover effects to be like ... you didn't read what I wrote ... I need that information, in order to re-apply the hover effect. sigh.

also, you said you wanted all the pictures in a column, and suddenly you want them side by side? Whaaa..? Could you maybe draw a picture of how you want the final result to look like? I will help you.